# How to get slug of product tag from it's name in wordpress+woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get product category's slug from it's name in wordpress+woocommerce. So i have this code:

```
$catname = 'clothes';
$tagname = get_term_by('name', $catname, 'product_tag');
$tagslug = $tagname->slug;
```

But $tagslug returns me empty string. What is wrong in my code?

I know that get_term_by() is the yhong that can do this. Maybe i use wrong syntax..

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is a typo in the above code . You have written **$cattname** instead of **$catname** on **line no 2**. Rest there is no issue with the syntax or the code.

Comment: Hi Akshay, i modified post, yes, there was misspelling. But it does not work anyway

Comment: In Which hook or template you are using this code ?